# SQL SELECT DISTINCT - Mirrored Columes

Tags: mysql

Tricky question, I need to write a SQL query where I want the links between two devices, but the two devices have their link information twice but mirrored... like this...

```
| LinkID | Source_Name | Source_Port | Destination_Name | Destination_Port|

|1       | Device1     | Gi1/0/1     | Device2          | Gi1/0/2         |

|2       | Device2     | Gi1/0/2     | Device1          | Gi1/0/1         |

|3       | Device2     | Gi1/0/1     | Device3          | Gi1/0/1         |

|4       | Device1     | Gi1/0/2     | Device3          | Gi1/0/2         |
```

so I want the query results to return rows 1,3,4 because those links are unique but I don't want row 2 because its telling me the same information as row 1... is this possible?

Comment: Did you tried anything yet?

Comment: How are you determining that row 1 and row 2 are the same - looks like each col has a different value?

Comment: yes the values are different, but row 1 and 2 have the same information but in different columns .... its defining the same link

Comment: Do you really need the row numbers, and if so why does 1 not 2 get retained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `RowNo` is set to auto increment , for your criteria you want to pick higher `RowNo` if rows sharing same `Name = DestinationDevice` and `SourcePort = DestinationPort` other than itself

```
SELECT 
  a.* 
FROM
  demo a 
  LEFT JOIN demo b 
    ON a.`Name` = b.`DestinationDevice` 
    AND a.`SourcePort` = b.`DestinationPort` 
    AND a.`RowNo` < b.`RowNo` 
WHERE b.`RowNo` IS NULL
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8b16c/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use a least/greatest trick here:

```
SELECT
    MIN(`Row No`) AS minRow, srcName, destName, srcPort, destPort
FROM
(
    SELECT
        `Row No`,
        LEAST(Name,           `Destination Device`) AS srcName,
        GREATEST(Name,        `Destination Device`) AS destName,
        LEAST(`Source Port`,    `Destination Port`) AS srcPort,
        GREATEST(`Source Port`, `Destination Port`) AS destPort
    FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY
    srcName, destName, srcPort, destPort
ORDER BY
    minRow;
```

### Demo

Comment: I tested your Query, It returned 8 out of 8 rows when it should have only return 4 :/

Comment: @Mas0490 My query works correctly in the demo for the data and output you provided.  If you expect something else, you should have asked a better question.

Comment: @Mas0490 Can you edit my demo, add your data, and then paste the link here?